How to make Vue 360 compatible with vuejs latest version
I am currently working on a project that spins product 360 degree. I have been using this library called vue-360 but only works with vuejs 2.
import VueThreeSixty from 'vue-360'

import 'vue-360/dist/css/style.css'

Vue.use(VueThreeSixty)

<vue-three-sixty 
  :amount=36
  imagePath="https://scaleflex.cloudimg.io/width/600/q35/https://scaleflex.ultrafast.io/https://scaleflex.airstore.io/demo/chair-360-36"
  fileName="chair_{index}.jpg?v1"
/>

now my question is, Is there a way where we can make this work with vuejs3?. I want to stick to the vuejs2 but I cannot since a lot of my code dependency doesn't work well with vuejs2
thanks

vue 2 plugins must be rewritten for vue 3.  there's nothing the end user can do to force compatibility.  you'll need to reach out to the maintainer or fork your own version and update the library yourself.

You could also give this one a try: https://naver.github.io/egjs-view360/docs/quick-start-vue

Notice what VueThreeSixty plugin is, https://github.com/rajeevgade/vue-360/blob/master/src/index.js#L8-L9 . You can try to take care of Hammer.js in Vue 3 yourself, and use I360Viewer component directly with v3 compat layer. This totally depends on how a comp is implemented in order for compat to workj, but it looks like it has a chance. Make sure you import it from vue-360/src/components/I360Viewer.vue rather than dist/ , as .vue should be compiled with v3 compiler. You'll need to replace vue-360 npm package with gh repo instead package because it doesn't include src/ , but this can work

Or you can just fork it and update for v3 with minimal changes instead of monkey-patching it, but make sure nobody already did this
